# Amadeus Self-Service API currency bug. Response always in origin country currency

Tags: amadeus

I originally reported this to Self-Service support in December, but I never got a response. I recently realized that, even in the production environment, selecting a currency parameter for an Inspiration or Cheapest-Date endpoint always returns the origin country's currency despite selecting another currency. (In the Low-Fare endpoint it seems to work as designed.) I tested this in both my web application and in Amadeus' own [explorer tool](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/203/api-doc/5/api-docs-and-example/10003). Here is a snip from the JSON response in the Explorer:

```
    "meta": {
    "currency": "EUR",
    "links": {
      "self": "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-dates?origin=MAD&destination=MUC&departureDate=2019-04-14,2019-10-10&oneWay=false&duration=4,7&nonStop=true&currency=USD&viewBy=DATE"
    },
    "defaults": {
      "departureDate": "2019-04-14,2019-10-10"
    }
  }
```

Notice that the meta.currency value is EUR, but the meta.links.self (the query I ran) shows a GET parameter of currency=USD. The same problem I reported in Dec.

I am posting this for suggestions about how to get some action from Amadeus (hope they read this), or a suggested workaround (obvious one is hiding Currency field from the Inspiration and Cheapest-Date form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currency parameter in Flight Inspiration and Cheapest Date Search, works only along with maxPrice. Prices in the response are computed in a currency determined by the origin/destination pair: they cannot be converted in a given currency.

Since it's a bit confusing, we are going to update the currency parameter naming and  documentation. Point taken and sorry for the delay in the response.

Comment: It is more than a bit confusing. Why was a currency parameter for those endpoints written into their documentation and explorer tool in the first place? That seems to have been a big oversight.